# why does the average temperature vary a lot from my setting temperature in nve?

Tags: molecular-dynamics

I set my t_start and t_stop as 0.52 (lj unit), and I ran the nvt first.[image] after it reached equilibration I ran the nve but found the temperature of the last 1000steps went up to 0.56 while my coworker still had the normal result around 0.52. [image]we even used the same code but our results are quite different. why does the average temperature vary so much from the one I set before?

Comment: my understanding is that initializing a stable thermal equilibrium in MD is very difficult, so a common practice is to start out with something, let it run, then reset the system energy to the correct thermal level you want

Comment: You will have to be more descriptive in what you are trying to do. I have no clue what software system it is you are using, and your question does not contain a description of what your goal is and how the results differ from your expectations.

Comment: What happens to the total energy of the system? Does it remain close to being constant even from before the last 1000 steps to the end?